# how to create family loop in php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

hi i am making a family relation using this  https://codepen.io/VividD/pen/fIFJt
and i want to get father and mother first then father and mother of father,father and mother of mother and it will go on for each parent until i reach the end of it. Data is needed in this form.

```
 function getData() {
return {  
    "name": "Clifford Shanks",
    "born": 1862,
    "died": 1906,
    "location": "Petersburg, VA",
    "parents": [
      {
        "name": "James Shanks",
        "born": 1831,
        "died": 1884,
        "location": "Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [
          {
            "name": "Robert Shanks",
            "born": 1781,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
          },
          {
            "name": "Elizabeth Shanks",
            "born": 1795,
            "died": 1871,
            "location": "Ireland/Petersburg, VA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Ann Emily Brown",
        "born": 1826,
        "died": 1866,
        "location": "Brunswick/Petersburg, VA",
        "parents": [
          {
            "name": "Henry Brown",
            "born": 1792,
            "died": 1845,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
          },
          {
            "name": "Sarah Houchins",
            "born": 1793,
            "died": 1882,
            "location": "Montgomery, NC"
          }
        ]
       }
       ]
       };
       };
```

i am unable to create infinite loop for it if anyone can help that will be great thanks.

Comment: Give us a correct array your given array not valid

Comment: please check updated answer also array is given in codepen link you can check it from there also

Comment: Why is this tagged with php and mysqli? Do you need a php solution or a javascript one?

Comment: i need a php solution i will echo this data in javascript then